# issue in conversion of bootstrap btn-group html code in php variable using anchor function

Tags: codeigniter, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

i am using codeigniter.i am trying to convert this bootstrap code into a php variable for HTML table class

```
   <div class="btn-group">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                Action <span class="caret"></span>
                            </button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-default pull-right" role="menu">


                                <li>
                                     <a href="#" onclick="showAjaxModal('<?php echo base_url();?>index.php?modal/popup/modal_take_payment/<?php echo $row['invoice_id'];?>');">
                                        <i class="entypo-bookmarks"></i>
                                            Take Payment                                        </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>

                                <!-- VIEWING LINK -->
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#" onclick="showAjaxModal('<?php echo base_url();?>index.php?modal/popup/modal_view_invoice/<?php echo $row['invoice_id'];?>');">
                                        <i class="entypo-credit-card"></i>
                                            View Invoice                                            </a>
                                                </li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>

                                <!-- EDITING LINK -->
                                <li>
                                 <a href="#" onclick="showAjaxModal('<?php echo base_url();?>index.php?modal/popup/modal_edit_invoice/<?php echo $row['invoice_id'];?>');">
                                        <i class="entypo-pencil"></i>
                                            Edit                                        </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>

                                <!-- DELETION LINK -->
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#" onclick="confirm_modal('<?php echo base_url();?>index.php?admin/invoice/delete/<?php echo $row['invoice_id'];?>');">
                                        <i class="entypo-trash"></i>
                                            Delete                                            </a>
                                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
```

[result of above HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTIQH.png)

now i want to convert this complete html code into a php syntax so i can use it in HTML table class and code for this is as below-

```
    [$edit_url =base_url().'index.php?modal/popup/modal_edit_invoice/'. $row\['invoice_id'\];
$url = base_url().'index.php?modal/popup/modal_take_payment/'. $row\['invoice_id'\];
$url_delete= base_url().'index.php?admin/invoice/delete/'. $row\['invoice_id'\];
$url_invoice= base_url().'index.php?modal/popup/modal_view_invoice/'. $row\['invoice_id'\];

$onclick_delete = array('onclick'=>"return confirm_modal('{$url_delete}')" , 'class'=>"btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle");
$onclick_edit = array('onclick'=>"return showAjaxModal('{$edit_url}')" , 'class'=>"btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle");
$onclick_take = array('onclick'=>"return showAjaxModal('{$url}')",'class'=>"btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle"); 
$onclick_invoice = array('onclick'=>"return showAjaxModal('{$url_invoice}')",'class'=>"btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle");
   $links = anchor('#', 'Take Payment',$onclick_take);
   $links .= anchor('#', 'edit',$onclick_edit);
   $links .= anchor('#', 'Invoice',$onclick_invoice);
   $links .= anchor('#', 'delete',$onclick_delete);
```

but this is not giving me the result as above html code. so can you please suggest me the changes in the code.

2. **problem_II**

and when i am using above code bootstrap model properties also not working as expected.the problem is Body is not auto scrolling to top when model is popup and for that reason model is not coming properly on my screen. although i didn't made any changes in **body.modal-open**. 
please help me out. thanks in advance

Comment: "not giving me the result as above html code".... so what is it giving you? limit your question to 1 per and provide enough information. also the html method with php helpers seems necessary to me. you know you can just return a view to a variable right? (third param true in load view) e.g. `$html = $this->load->view('somepage', $data, true)`

Comment: thanx alex... problem solved with code-  $html = $this->load->view('somepage', $data, true)

Comment: it's really very helpful for me